# Twitter bootstrap: get rid of 1200px large display how?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

If you look at: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive they have categories for nearly every device. I'd like to eliminate the last support device entry:

```
Large display   1200px and up   70px    30px
```

I'm a backend programmer, not a designer, so my css knowledge is limited. Can someone point me to the files I would need to modify in order to get rid of support for large display?

Thanks!

(PS if anyone is wondering why I would do this, it's corporate standard blah blah blah 1024px blah blah.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok this wasn't that hard, starting on line 437 of bootstrap-responsive.css, remove this entire section:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
...
}
```

Now just change this one line

```
@media (max-width: 979px) {
```

to this:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
```

easy hack!

EDIT better explanation:

If you look at bootstrap-responsive.css, and you look at all the crap except the "Media Queries" you'd be left with basically the following outline:

```
/* Landscape phones and down */
  @media (max-width: 480px) { ... }

  /* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
  @media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

  /* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }

  /* Desktop */
  @media (max-width: 979px) { ... }

  /* Large desktop */
  @media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

See how it gradually scales up? What I did is remove the last section, then changed the 2nd to last to take it's place.

EDIT:

BTW, if you use the boostrap customization wizard, you can do this on their GUI by unselecting large monitor support.

Comment: I don't understand your change. What about the devices smaller than 1200 px?

Comment: Sadly they have remove the customization wizard now version 3 is getting released

Answer (score 10):

If you are using the maxcdn version of bootstrap or just dont want to touch the source, just paste place the following css after loading the bootstrap stylesheet.

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container,
    .navbar-static-top .container,
    .navbar-fixed-top .container,
    .navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
      width: 940px;
    }
    .row-fluid {
      width: 100%;
      *zoom: 1;
    }
    .row-fluid:before,
    .row-fluid:after {
      display: table;
      content: "";
      line-height: 0;
    }
    .row-fluid:after {
      clear: both;
    }
    .row-fluid [class*="span"] {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 30px;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      float: left;
      margin-left: 2.127659574468085%;
      *margin-left: 2.074468085106383%;
    }
    .row-fluid [class*="span"]:first-child {
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    .row-fluid .controls-row [class*="span"] + [class*="span"] {
      margin-left: 2.127659574468085%;
    }
    .row-fluid .span12 {
      width: 100%;
      *width: 99.94680851063829%;
    }
    .row-fluid .span11 {
      width: 91.48936170212765%;
      *width: 91.43617021276594%;
    }
    .row-fluid .span10 {
      width: 82.97872340425532%;
      *width: 82.92553191489361%;
    }
    .row-fluid .span9 {
      width: 74.46808510638297%;
      *width: 74.41489361702126%;
    }
    .row-fluid .span8 {
      width: 65.95744680851064%;
      *width: 65.90425531914893%;
    }
    .row-fluid .span7 {
      width: 57.44680851063829%;
      *width: 57.39361702127659%;
    }
    .row-fluid .span6 {
      width: 48.93617021276595%;
      *width: 48.88297872340425%;
    }
    .row-fluid .span5 {
      width: 40.42553191489362%;
      *width: 40.37234042553192%;
    }
    .row-fluid .span4 {
      width: 31.914893617021278%;
      *width: 31.861702127659576%;
    }
    .row-fluid .span3 {
      width: 23.404255319148934%;
      *width: 23.351063829787233%;
    }
    .row-fluid .span2 {
      width: 14.893617021276595%;
      *width: 14.840425531914894%;
    }
    .row-fluid .span1 {
      width: 6.382978723404255%;
      *width: 6.329787234042553%;
    }
    .row-fluid .offset12 {
      margin-left: 104.25531914893617%;
      *margin-left: 104.14893617021275%;
    }
    .row-fluid .offset12:first-child {
      margin-left: 102.12765957446808%;
      *margin-left: 102.02127659574467%;
    }
    .row-fluid .offset11 {
      margin-left: 95.74468085106382%;
      *margin-left: 95.6382978723404%;
    }
    .row-fluid .offset11:first-child {
      margin-left: 93.61702127659574%;
      *margin-left: 93.51063829787232%;
    }
    .row-fluid .offset10 {
      margin-left: 87.23404255319149%;
      *margin-left: 87.12765957446807%;
    }
    .row-fluid .offset10:first-child {
      margin-left: 85.1063829787234%;
      *margin-left: 84.99999999999999%;
    }
    .row-fluid .offset9 {
      margin-left: 78.72340425531914%;
      *margin-left: 78.61702127659572%;
    }
    .row-fluid .offset9:first-child {
      margin-left: 76.59574468085106%;
      *margin-left: 76.48936170212764%;
    }
    .row-fluid .offset8 {
      margin-left: 70.2127659574468%;
      *margin-left: 70.10638297872339%;
    }
    .row-fluid .offset8:first-child {
      margin-left: 68.08510638297872%;
      *margin-left: 67.9787234042553%;
    }
    .row-fluid .offset7 {
      margin-left: 61.70212765957446%;
      *margin-left: 61.59574468085106%;
    }
    .row-fluid .offset7:first-child {
      margin-left: 59.574468085106375%;
      *margin-left: 59.46808510638297%;
    }
    .row-fluid .offset6 {
      margin-left: 53.191489361702125%;
      *margin-left: 53.085106382978715%;
    }
    .row-fluid .offset6:first-child {
      margin-left: 51.063829787234035%;
      *margin-left: 50.95744680851063%;
    }
    .row-fluid .offset5 {
      margin-left: 44.68085106382979%;
      *margin-left: 44.57446808510638%;
    }
    .row-fluid .offset5:first-child {
      margin-left: 42.5531914893617%;
      *margin-left: 42.4468085106383%;
    }
    .row-fluid .offset4 {
      margin-left: 36.170212765957444%;
      *margin-left: 36.06382978723405%;
    }
    .row-fluid .offset4:first-child {
      margin-left: 34.04255319148936%;
      *margin-left: 33.93617021276596%;
    }
    .row-fluid .offset3 {
      margin-left: 27.659574468085104%;
      *margin-left: 27.5531914893617%;
    }
    .row-fluid .offset3:first-child {
      margin-left: 25.53191489361702%;
      *margin-left: 25.425531914893618%;
    }
    .row-fluid .offset2 {
      margin-left: 19.148936170212764%;
      *margin-left: 19.04255319148936%;
    }
    .row-fluid .offset2:first-child {
      margin-left: 17.02127659574468%;
      *margin-left: 16.914893617021278%;
    }
    .row-fluid .offset1 {
      margin-left: 10.638297872340425%;
      *margin-left: 10.53191489361702%;
    }
    .row-fluid .offset1:first-child {
      margin-left: 8.51063829787234%;
      *margin-left: 8.404255319148938%;
    }
}
```

Basically it enforces the 960px css for the 1200px.

Comment: 940 was too small for me, so i changed it to width: 1003px; and its working great. thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 6):

There is no need to hack or update the bootstrap CSS files. You can disable the effects by restraining the container to grow further. Use:

```
.container-fluid,
.container {
  // Disable large-desktop breakpoint.
  max-width: $container-md;
}
```

The `$container-md` value is typically `970px`, unless you changed the `$grid-gutter-width`. For LESS, replace the `$` of variables with an `@`. For regular CSS, replace the variable with the hard coded pixel size.

Comment: Agree, this wasn't always possible though. Upvoting for a modern answer!

Answer (score 5):

Best yet just remove:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

and it will only ever use the formatting for `@media (max-width: 979px)` for all desktop sizes

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to this is setting the 1200px grid variables to those values for the regular grid values.  With this method you can avoid updating the source and avoid upgrade issues:

@gridColumnWidth1200: 60px;

@gridGutterWidth1200: 20px;